# How do I mock the http requests in my case

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am having a weird issue regarding my unit test.
In controller I have something like

```
testFactory.testFunction($scope.id)
       .then(function(returnData) {
           // do something with the return
       })
```

Factory file

```
test.testFunction = function(id) {
        return $http.get('/api/v.10/book/' + id + '/books');
};
```

unit test

```
var books = {data: {id: 333, name: 'my book'}};

beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_, _testFactory_) {
        scope        = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        testFactory = _testFactory_;

        testCtrl = _$controller_('testCtrl', {
            $scope: scope
        });

        $httpBackend.whenGET('/api/v.10/book/333/books').respond(books);
    }));


 it('should check if test runs', function() {
         testFactory.testFunction(333).then(function(returnData){
                console.log(returnData)
         })
         $httpBackend.flush();
  })
```

For some reason, the console.log for the 'returnData' add the 'books' variable to an objects and add headers, status…etc to the response.

For example:

```
Object{data: Object{data: Object{id: ..., name: ...}}, 
             status: 200, headers: function (name) { ... }, 
             transformResponse: [...], 
             url: '/api/v.10/book/333/books', statusText: ''}
```

I am only expecting

`{data: {id: 333, name: 'my book''}}` as my response.

Can someone help me about the issue?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `return` is a reserved word in Javascript. That might be causing some issues assuming you are actually using that as your variable name.

Comment: Thanks, it was just a bad return data name. It isn't like that in my real codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `respond` with a single parameter, it should be the data object you want returned to your web service, [as shown under `when` in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#when). So you need to change your `books` variable to just `{id: 333, name: 'my book'}`.